# how to configure mcp79410 for Raspberry pi?

Tags: rtc, mcp79410

I was trying to configure an MCP79410 with a Raspberry Pi using steps showed [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61652/67301). Each step worked well I tried the command, `hwclock -w`. In response, I got the error message:

```
hwclock: Time out waiting for time change.
hwclock: The Hardware clock does not contain a valid time, so we cannot set the System Time from it. Unable to set system clock.
```

Which is the same response I got for `hwclock -r`

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: What response did you get from `i2cdetect`?

Comment: i2cdetect -y 1 command repose is following :-
 `    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --`

Comment: Comments are *really, really* bad places to try and post structured ASCII - you can see what it's done to the formatting. It would be an awful lot easier to read if you edited that information into the main body of your question.

Comment: @goobering I'm really sorry for posting structured ASCII in comment section, I'm new here. Thanks for your suggestion. Btw, the problem is solved. The problem was in hardware. By replacing MCP79410, the system  works fine.

Comment: No problem at all, there's an *Edit* button directly below your question that you can use to move the text from the comment into the question body. I'm really pleased that you've figured the problem out - if you've come up with an answer please post it (and grab yourself some more points!).